# converting angular2 app to use webpack instead of systemjs. Error with momentjs

Tags: webpack, momentjs

I am converting an existing angular2 app to use webpack as the bundling mechanism for production.

I keep getting the error  error 
**TS1192: Module '"C:/projects/******/node_modules/moment/moment"' has no default export.**

I'm importing moment in the typescript code by using the following:
import moment from 'moment';

I've added the link in the files section of the tsconfig.json file:
"node_modules/moment/moment.d.ts",

I'm upgrading the app to use webpack and I am on the first step of bundling the app.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please refer to this [github ticket](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2608)

Comment: Thank you!!! worked perfect